# importance of a particular subring of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Tags: ring-theory

The subring of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ which contains all rational polynomials with constant term integer sits in between $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ both of which is Noetherian, but this subring is not so although it has properties very much similar to UFD. Does this has any particular interest and any generalization?

Comment: Yes, rings of the form $\,R + x F[x]\,$ often prove handy for (counter)examples in ring theory. See the paper by Zafrullah cited [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/14360/242) for a survey of their properties.